# what does it mean -> public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException

Tags: java, exception

When we write this ->

```
void add() throws ArithmeticException
```

it indicates the method `add` may or may not throw an `ArithmeticException`. So the calling method has to write try and catch block, to handle this exception. Then what does it mean when we write this ->

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
```

even if `main` method throws `IOException` there is no calling method to handle it. So what does it mean when we write main method throws an exception?

Comment: What happens when you write a class with a main and throw an exception from it? Give it a try.

Comment: It means it is throwing an exception and this won't be handled at all.

Comment: The only difference is that there will be nothing to catch the exception since you will be at the top of YOUR class. But there is still the JVM to "print it" and stop the process (just like an RuntimeException that you don't catch)

Comment: Google [`java main throws`](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+main+throws), and you will find such gems as "[What would happen if we add "throws Exception" to the main method in java?](https://www.quora.com/What-would-happen-if-we-add-throws-Exception-to-the-main-method-in-java)" and "[How does the JVM handle an exception thrown by the main method?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/257174/202153)"

Answer (score 0):

Because IOException is a checked Exception and main is just a method like any other, than if a checked Exception is thrown in a method, it has to be declared in the method signature. In other words, main might be the entry point, but it could also be called like any method, and even as an entry point it's called by other code in the JVM.

Answer (score 0):

The main method is not really any different from any other method. It is only special because it is defined as the entry point of your application. In the event that it throws an exception, and there is no handler, your program will crash and cease to function. However, there are scenarios where the main method can be handled. For example:

```
public class a{
        public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException{
                throw IOException;
        }
}

//some other class:
String[] args = {};
new a().main(args);
```

Comment: You could simply `a.main(args);` ;) but should be `A.main(args);` but I never found the need to call the starting method again.

Comment: @AxelH args! (get it?) You're right I should have just used that instead. Thank you. I've re-called the starting method only to fully restart an application without actually closing out of it. A weird trick that can surprisingly work well sometimes. You never know!

Answer (score 0):

> what does it mean -> public static void main(String[] args) throws
>   IOException

it means, the main method is not catching any exceptions, instead it handles the `IOException` by throwing it to the source which invoked the main method.

You throw `Exception` if you want it to be handled by higher function or calling function.

remember, when you throw `Exception` The exception doesn't just disappear, It stil has to be handled by calling function. otherwise it'll crash the program.

Example :

```
 public void iThrowException() throws Exception{
  throw new Exception("It has to be handled!");
}
```

whenever you want to call this method you should call inside `try/catch` block
like this

```
 public void iWillHandleIt(){
  try{
    iThrowException();
  }catch(Exception e){
    System.err.println("Exception caught: "+e);
  }
}
```

As in your case if you throw Exception from main method, caller of main() method i.e.; JVM need to handle the exception. otherwise it will lead to crash.

you'll get better idea if you go throw [Read more about Checked and UncheckedExceptions here](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=129)

Comment: It's not the question. Here the question is specificly about the `public static void main(String... args)` method. "Why to add a `throws` to the "bottom" of the stack call?" "What happen if it is thrown?",  ...

Comment: As i told in my answer "caller of main() method has to handle it  i.e.; JVM, otherwise it will lead to crash

Comment: Where ?? You mean there "_remember, when you throw Exception The exception doesn't just disappear, It stil has to be handled by calling function. otherwise it'll crash the program._" ? Well I want to see how you will catch the exception thrown by the main method then (in the general usage of the method). EDIT : Now at least, it is mention that this is done by the execution code of the JVM.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] Args) throws IOException
{
......
}
```

where this specifies that the method may going to throws IOException and insist the compiler that the block which is calling this method needs some special attention towards this regarding handling or again throwing back.

throws IOException: the logic present within the main method performs some I/O related tasks, and to make sure that the program does not crash owing to some I/O related issues, this work as a fail- safe. Alternately, wrapping the responsible code within a try- catch construct also works.